# Airflow Task triggered manually but remains in queued state

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

I am using Airflow 2.3.1 and running with Local Executor against MS SQL Server as metadata db.

I am trying to execute a dag manually, it shows as queued but nothing happens. There is no other tasks running when this dag is triggered. When I hover on the task, it says "Not yet started".

Tried restarting the scheduler and webserver, but nothing different. The code of the dag is as follows

> from datetime import datetime, timedelta import pendulum from airflow
> import  DAG from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator from
> airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
>
> default_args = {
> 'owner': 'airflow',
> 'start_date': datetime(2022,5,27),
> 'email': False,
> 'email_on_failure': False,
> 'email_on_retry': False,
> 'retries': 1,
> 'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5), }
>
> MIDT_dag = DAG(
> 'Dag_1',
> default_args=default_args,
> catchup=False,
> description='Test DAG',
> schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1) )
>
> task_1 = BashOperator(
> task_id='first_task',
> bash_command= r"/srv/python3_8_13/venv/bin/python /srv/source_code/InputToRawMIDT_Amadeus_Spark_Linux.py",
> dag=MIDT_dag, )
>
> task_2 = BashOperator(
> task_id='second_task',
> bash_command='echo Testing',
> dag=MIDT_dag, )
>
> task_1 >> task_2

Appreciate any help.

Thanks
Manoj George

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your DAG is disabled.

open the UI, choose DAGS in the menu and enabled it.

[image]